# Set object at iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

In a parent view, I'm passing a part of a backbone model (the model is called Library, so I pass the `Library.book` object as `this.book`. When I alert `this.book`, it looks something like:

```
{"favoritePages":["384","383","385"],"summariesOfFavoritePages":["Cool","Great","Informative"]}
```

I have a backbone view that looks like:

```
var LibraryBookView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    if (options) {
       _.extend(this, options);
    }
  },
  render: function () {

     // FOR TESTING
     alert(JSON.stringify(this.book));

     var that = this;

     $(".test").on('click', function(e) {
         var id = $(this).data("id");
         var pagesIndex = $.inArray( id + "", that.book.favoritePages );
         that.book.favoritePages[pagesIndex] = "DELETED"; // BASICALLY WHAT I WANT TO DO WITH BACKONE'S SET
     });

  }
});
```

The Library View (the Parent View) part that passes the model looks like:

```
var LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
     if (options) {
        _.extend(this, options);
     }
     this.render();

     _.each(this.model.get("library").books, function(book){

        var libraryBookView = new LibraryBookView({
           el: $('.content'),
           book: book,
           model: this.model
        });

        libraryBookView.render();
     });
 },
```

Basically, I want to update `this.book` with `this.model.set` but not sure how to do it with the array inside the iteration of books?

Comment: Seems like your library should be a collection and each book should be a model - if you model the data like that it will become simpler, then  LibraryBookView will simply take a model (of the book) and you can update it easily.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mis-clicked on the bounty reason. I meant to go for "Not enough attention". How can I change this?

Comment: @DominicTobias, This would be the ideal situation, unfortunately, it's a legacy app where I can't change easily. Is there a solution I could use with the current model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of couple of solutions:

- Same as suggested by @Lochemage. Use bookIndex, but the assumption is book index won't change. For setting the model, I would suggest following :

> if( this.model.get('library').books[this.bookIndex] != undefined )
>      this.model.get('library').books[this.bookIndex] = this.book;

- Use Underscore library's [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) method. The assumption is `book` is unique in all `library.books` attribute.

> ```
> var book = _.findWhere(this.model.get("library").books, this.book);
> if(book != undefined)
> book = this.book;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can try also remembering the book index inside your LibraryBookView.

```
_.each(this.model.get("library").books, function(book, bookIndex){
   var libraryBookView = new LibraryBookView({
      el: $('.content'),
      book: book,
      bookIndex: bookIndex,
      model: this.model
   });

   libraryBookView.render();
});
```

Then in your library book class, where you want to set the model:

```
this.model.set('library.books[' + this.bookIndex + ']', this.book);
```

This is assuming your book index's won't change... if they do, then you will have to either update the index on each library book view, or do something else.